# How to get low level access to JavaFX chart so an image can be drawn?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to draw an image behind the LineChart so that any grid and lines are drawn over the image.  It seems LineChart would need to expose some lower level accessor to the Canvas so this could be done.

```
public class ChartBgImageTest {
    public ChartBgImageTest() {

        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 21, 0.1);
        final LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getDefaultScreenDevice()
                .getDefaultConfiguration()
                .createCompatibleImage(600, 400);


        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(600, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        img.createGraphics().fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        // Fill img code here

        Graphics g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

        // TODO How to draw the img to lineChart background.
        // So that any grids or lines on the chart are drawn above the img.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The charts in the `javafx.scene.chart` package don't use a `Canvas` to draw the charts. They instead use the scene graph. In your question you're creating an image on the fly, but assuming you have an already-created image, possibly as an embedded resource, you could use CSS to add the image to the chart's background. Looking at the `XYChart` section of [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#xychart), you'll see one of the substructures is labeled `chart-plot-background` and is a `Region`, which means a background image can be applied to it via CSS. For example:

**App.java:**

```java
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis(), createChartData());
    chart.getXAxis().setLabel("X");
    chart.getYAxis().setLabel("Y");

    var scene = new Scene(chart, 1000, 650);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toString());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private static ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>> createChartData() {
    var random = new Random();

    var chartData = FXCollections.<Series<Number, Number>>observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      var data = FXCollections.<Data<Number, Number>>observableArrayList();
      for (int j = 0; j <= 15; j++) {
        data.add(new Data<>(j, random.nextInt(250)));
      }
      chartData.add(new Series<>("Series #" + i, data));
    }
    return chartData;
  }
}
```

**style.css:**

```css
.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-image: url(/* your URL */);
    -fx-background-size: cover;
}
```

That will only draw the image behind the actual chart content (i.e. the data). The axis, legend, and surrounding space won't have the image behind it. If you want the *entire* chart to have the background image then you can utilize the fact that `Chart`, which all chart implementations inherit from, extends from `Region`. Change the CSS to:

```css
.chart {
    -fx-background-image: url(/* your URL */);
    -fx-background-size: cover;
}

.chart-plot-background,
.chart-legend {
    -fx-background-color: null;
}
```

If you want something between the plot background and the entire chart you can add the image to `.chart-content` (documented [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#chart)).

---

If you have to stay within code (e.g. because you're creating the image on the fly) then you'll have to get a reference to the necessary `Region`. To do that you can use [`Node#lookup(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup(java.lang.String)). Be aware, however, that you may need to wait until the chart has been rendered on screen before calling `lookup`, as it's possible the needed descendant node has not been created and added to the scene graph beforehand (this is especially true of controls).

```java
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis(), createChartData());
    chart.setTitle("Example Chart");
    chart.getXAxis().setLabel("X");
    chart.getYAxis().setLabel("Y");

    var scene = new Scene(chart, 1000, 650);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    var plotBackground = (Region) chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
    plotBackground.setBackground(
        new Background(
            new BackgroundImage(
                new Image(/* your URL */),
                null,
                null,
                BackgroundPosition.CENTER,
                new BackgroundSize(0, 0, false, false, true, false))));
  }

  private static ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>> createChartData() {
    var random = new Random();

    var chartData = FXCollections.<Series<Number, Number>>observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      var data = FXCollections.<Data<Number, Number>>observableArrayList();
      for (int j = 0; j <= 15; j++) {
        data.add(new Data<>(j, random.nextInt(250)));
      }
      chartData.add(new Series<>("Series #" + i, data));
    }
    return chartData;
  }
}
```

Notice that you can't use `BufferedImage` directly with the JavaFX API. If you need to actually draw an `Image` in code you have a few options:

- Use a [`WritableImage`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) directly (via its `PixelWriter`). This does not provide a nice API, such as `fillRect(...)`.
- Draw to a [`Canvas`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) then [create a snapshot](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot(javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)) of the result.
- Use [`SwingFXUtils#toFXImage(BufferedImage,WritableImage)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#toFXImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage,javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)) to convert a `BufferedImage` into a JavaFX `Image`

Comment: Using css is not what i want to do, but thanks for the detailed answer. Can you provide an example using WriteableImage/PixelWriter.

Comment: That's why I provided a non-CSS solution as well, just in case :) What sort of example are you looking for? Once you have a reference to the [`PixelWriter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html) (via `WritableImage#getPixelWriter()`) you just call the appropriate methods on it to set the color of each pixel.

Comment: If you're not aware, `WritableImage` extends `Image`, so it can be used wherever an `Image` is used.

Comment: how can i get a ref to PixelWriter from the LineChart?

Comment: You don't. You create a `WritableImage` instance, get it's `PixelWriter`, draw to it, then set the `background` property of the chart (or some descendant region of the chart) to a `BackgroundImage` using the `WritableImage` as the image. I show some of this in my second example, near the end of the answer. Note if you draw to the `PixelWriter` later then the background image should reflect the changes automatically.

Comment: You may need to use different `BackgroundPosition` and `BackgroundSize` to get the desired effect.

Comment: makes sense ill give it a shot!